# Elasticsearch support for spark 2.4.2 with scala 2.12

Tags: apache-spark, elasticsearch, spark-structured-streaming

I'm not able to find any ES 6.7.1 supporting jar for spark 2.4.2 with scala 2.12
In maven repo only scala 2.11 and 2.10 is supported for the jar.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>6.7.1</version>
</dependency>
```

For my application we are using spark 2.4.2 which supports only scala 2.12 version.
Following is the error shown when I try to run with "elasticsearch-spark-20_2.11" jar

```
StreamingExecutionRelation KafkaV2[Subscribe[test_topic]], [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13]

        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:302)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:193)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DataFrameValueWriter.writeStruct(DataFrameValueWriter.scala:78)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DataFrameValueWriter.write(DataFrameValueWriter.scala:70)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.DataFrameValueWriter.write(DataFrameValueWriter.scala:53)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.builder.ContentBuilder.value(ContentBuilder.java:53)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.bulk.TemplatedBulk.doWriteObject(TemplatedBulk.java:71)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.bulk.TemplatedBulk.write(TemplatedBulk.java:58)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.serialization.bulk.BulkEntryWriter.writeBulkEntry(BulkEntryWriter.java:68)
        at org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.RestRepository.writeToIndex(RestRepository.java:170)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.rdd.EsRDDWriter.write(EsRDDWriter.scala:74)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsStreamQueryWriter.run(EsStreamQueryWriter.scala:41)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink$$anonfun$addBatch$2$$anonfun$2.apply(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:52)
        at org.elasticsearch.spark.sql.streaming.EsSparkSqlStreamingSink$$anonfun$addBatch$2$$anonfun$2.apply(EsSparkSqlStreamingSink.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:411)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:414)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: elasticsearch support for Spark/scala (2.12) seems to be released yesterday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for the delay,

We can't use Elasticsearch Spark / Elasticsearch Hadoop libraries yet with Scala 2.12. There exists an opened merge request (https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop/pull/1308) which is pending, waiting for tests to pass.

You either have to downgrade your project to use Scala 2.11 or have to wait for the libraries to be released on Scala 2.12

Answer (score 1):

The last Maven release for that project was in [November 2016](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch-spark) and Scala 2.12 is still not supported.

This is unfortunate because Spark 3 requires Scala 2.12, so if your project depends on elasticsearch-spark, then you can't upgrade to Spark 3.

[elasticsearch-hadoop](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-hadoop) claims to support Spark and looks to be actively maintained, so that might be your best bet.

As mentioned in [this post](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/upgrate-to-spark-3-scala-2-12/) watch out for what your depend on in the Spark / Scala world because dependencies are often abandoned, leaving users in difficult situations.